# swift display an image in another view controller when pressed button

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

How to display an image in another view controller when pressing on button? I have two button and pressing first button, it should show an image, pressing another button, it should show an another image. I don't want the use View Controller for each button.I watched some videos about segues but i couldn't.

Comment: What errors do you get? Where is your symbolicated crash log? Please add the relevant MCVE code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 segues (1 for each button). You do this in storyboard by control dragging from the button to the image view controller. Then click on the segue it self and select Attributes inspector in storyboard and write "firstSegue" as the identifier for the first segue and "secondSegue" as the identifier for the second segue.

add this to the view controller with the buttons:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "firstSegue" {

        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? NameOfViewControllerWithImage {
            destinationVC.myimage = self.imagetoset
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "secondSegue" {

        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? NameOfViewControllerWithImage {
            destinationVC.myimage = self.someotherimagetoset
        }
    }

}
```

add an imageView and this code to the view controller with the image

```
var myimage: UIImage?
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.imageView.image = myimage
}
```

Comment: for 'imagetoset' and 'someotherimagetoset' should i make variable or instead of them should i write image.png ?? (sorry for bad english)

Comment: UIImage(named:”imagename.png”)

Comment: Could you tell me a little more detail, please? and i get that error :

Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'SecondViewController'

Comment: Try printing out some text in various places inside the prepeare function to see how the code behaves. Make sure in storyboard you selected the SecondViewController as the class in identity inspector.

Comment: i tried UIImage(named: "imagename.png") instead of imagetoset but it show   "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIImageView'"

Comment: You should ask a new question, showing your code and explaining the problem.